# How to handle passwords in shared code

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

This is a general git question.  I am a newbie to source control and want to share my repo with other developers but my code has a login and password in it (for Parse.com's API) which I don't want them to see.  I can see a couple options:

1) Don't include the login and password in my source code.  When I build the app I manually copy/paste the login and password into the right place, compile, then remove the login and password before the next commit. This is extremely tedious.

2) Setup two repos. One private repo for myself which has the login and password in the code and one for sharing.  I would manually remove the login and password whenever I needed to update the shared repo from the private one.

3) Some feature of git or sourcetree that I don't know about which hides the login and password from everyone except me.

How do others do this? Are there best practices?

Comment: have you checked out https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox may be worth a look too.

Comment: FWIW, Heroku's solution to this is to stick all such things in a file called `.env` in `key=value` form, then uses a pretty simple script to make everything in that file an environment variable. You can separate your production and dev logins easily this way too.

Comment: @dbarnes:  blackbox is what I was looking for. Hopefully someday this functionality will be built into the VCS.

Answer (score 2):

One accepted practise is to keep such login/auth credentials in a separate config file, and keep a copy of that config file checked in with dummy values.

Then, while sharing, you share the repository with other users using the dummy/test values, but while deploying, you either overwrite the config, or specify the environment in the application to pick up those values from the environment. For doing this, you would need to explore deployment scripts, like capistrano.